# ValueError: 'editdistance/bycython.pyx' doesn't match any files when downloading keras_ocr

Tags: python, keras, pip

When trying to download kera_ocr through pip, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: 'editdistance/bycython.pyx' doesn't match any files
```

I have tried everything I can think of.

1. Upgrading pip
2. Upgrading python
3. Installing dependencies

Comment: This might help you.https://github.com/roy-ht/editdistance/issues/94

Comment: @ewokx if you put this as an answer I will accept it and this question can be resolved. thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is that editdistance/bycython.pyx doesn't exist in the pypi archive for the editdistance pip package.

According to [1], you install the v0.6.2 version.

(While it shouldn't go away, but here's what is needed to be done)

pip install git+https://github.com/roy-ht/editdistance.git@v0.6.2.

But I suspect that once v0.6.2 hits pypi,  a `pip install editdistance` will work or if you do already have it, `pip install --upgrade editdistance`.

[1] - https://github.com/roy-ht/editdistance/issues/94#issuecomment-1426279375