# Can't install chs

Tags: python

When I try to execute `pip3 install chs` I get the following error:

```
pip3 install chs
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting chs
  Using cached chs-3.0.0.tar.gz (13.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: python-chess in ./.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from chs) (1.999)
Collecting editdistance (from chs)
  Using cached editdistance-0.6.2.tar.gz (31 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/fedora/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/fedora/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/home/fedora/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xq8q7ikf/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xq8q7ikf/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xq8q7ikf/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 25, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xq8q7ikf/overlay/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1010, in cythonize
          module_list, module_metadata = create_extension_list(
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xq8q7ikf/overlay/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 845, in create_extension_list
          for file in nonempty(sorted(extended_iglob(filepattern)), "'%s' doesn't match any files" % filepattern):
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xq8q7ikf/overlay/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 117, in nonempty
          raise ValueError(error_msg)
      ValueError: 'editdistance/bycython.pyx' doesn't match any files
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I'm new to Python so I'm having a hard time debugging.  It seems the issue is occurring from `editdistance` package.

I tried using a constraint file to force a different version of `editdistance` but no versions seem to pass the installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ValueError: 'editdistance/bycython.pyx' doesn't match any files when downloading keras_ocr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77484622/valueerror-editdistance-bycython-pyx-doesnt-match-any-files-when-downloading) and in turn https://github.com/roy-ht/editdistance/issues/94#issuecomment-1426279375 you need to install `editdistance` directly from the GitHub Release.
So try running `pip install git+https://github.com/roy-ht/editdistance.git@v0.6.2` before running `pip3 install chs`.